# Laravel 5.8.38 Error 419 Token Mismatch only on production server in Firefox Only

Tags: php, ajax, firefox, laravel-5.8, csrf-token

I got some problem on my laravel website but only on Firefox when already on production, it works fine on chrome even new edge.

On Chrome and Edge will be return (200) my dd($request->all()); So i can see variable i pass to controller.
But On Firefox, return with 419 status code "No Reason Phrase" and the response message is CSRF token mismatch.

like this:

> message   CSRF token mismatch.
> exception Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Exception\HttpException
> file  /var/www/html/voucher/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Exceptions/Handler.php
> line  208

What is the problem? Why only firefox return error 419 token mismatch?

This is Ajax code on Blade...

```
$(document).on('click', '.edit-Btn', function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    var token = $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content');
    var id = $(this).attr('id');
    
    $.ajax({
        url: "{{ route('category.get') }}",
        method: "POST",
        data: {
            _token: token,
            id: id,
        },
        dataType: "json",
        success:function(data){
            // console.log(data);
            var data = data['category'];
            $('#id-edit').val(data[0].id_category);
            $('#category-edit').val(data[0].category_name);
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: Perhaps some of your javascript code isn't supported by Mozilla.
Check your console.